# How to connect portable monitor USB Type-C to graphic card with display port or hdmi

Tags: hdmi, displayport, usb-c

I'm building a new computer, which is basically a very mobile itx PC. I've bought ASUS MB169C+ Portable Monitor and Gigabyte GeForce GTX 1070 G1, here's my problem:

ASUS MB169C+ monitor can be connected only with USB Type-C port.

GeForce has the following:

- Dual-link DVI-D
- 1, HDMI-2.0b
- 1, Display Port-1.4

Do I need some kind of adapter ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Besides video signal, also power should be delivered through that USB cable, so I'm afraid it won't be so easy.

[Official site of ASUS](https://www.asus.com/us/Monitors/MB169C-plus/) lists only a few devices and motherboards being compatible with the monitor:

> ASUS G752 notebook (17.3-inch)
>   ASUS UX501VW notebook (15.6-inch)
>   Apple MacBook (12-inch)
>   Chromebook Pixel (12.85-inch)
>
> ASUS Maximus VIII Extreme motherboard
>   ASUS Z170-Premium motherboard

Comment: Thanks, after doing lots of research I decided to cancel my order and sent this monitor back. It's really awesome, but not compatible with most on hadrware on the market.

Comment: I had the same problem. Bought this monitor thinking that of course they would have made it backwards compatible. No such luck!

Comment: Note that power itself is not the problem; you could provide an AC adapter or get the power from two USB ports. The problem is simply that no one made the necessary adapter.

Comment: Thanks, just cancelled my order.